# getting segmentation fault(core dump)after typing all the value in a vector in c++

Tags: c++, string, vector

i have made this code to print a string and int.

```
 vector<int> nu;

for(int v;cin>>v;)
    nu.push_back(v);

vector<string> la;
for(string c;cin>>c;)
    la.push_back(c);
```

the programme runs and starts taking value but as i put anything other than int to stop the

```
for(int v;cin>>v;)
```

part i get segmentation fault.all variables are defined locally so i do not understand why i am getting this error.

EDIT: for printing i have created a function

```
void print(vector<string> a,vector<int> b)
{int y=0;
y= b.size();
for(int i=0;i<y;i++)
    {cout<<a[i]<<" "<<b[i]<<"\n";
     }

}
```

Comment: You are not showing the code which prints. The error is likely there. In order to get help and avoid your question being closed, please provide a small compileable program which reproduces the error. (Usually in preparing that you find the error...)

Comment: One typical structured way to tackle similar problems is to separate "data acquisition" from "data processing". Start with the processing. Code a function which simply takes data (e.g. a vector, or perhaps two) and knows nothing about where it comes from or how it was filled. Print all the data, or whatever, with a test program which hard-codes some vectors (perhaps with an empty vector as a test case...). When you are sure your core functionality is working, deal with the input mechanism.

Comment: Also, C++ stream input is less than intuitive. For example, your stream is probably in a bad state after the failed read of an int, and will not let you input anything else before you clear() it.

Comment: ^ This is very important. With the code we see (unless you omitted `clear()` call), `la` will be empty, no matter what is later input, and you seem to expect that it will be same length as `nu`.

Comment: I'm seeing `nu.size()` is 3 and `la.size()` is 0.  I'm using input `1 2 3 x`.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: You have two vectors a and b and you running a loop with i as index for both of the arrays. It might be problem when array sizes are different in a and b and you may try  to access an element outside of its boundary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not access vectors before you have checked their size. You only check vector `b` but also access vector `a` which is likely empty because the input failed (because you didn't clear the stream after you entered something that could not be parsed as an int, so the second input loop was never entered).

Comment: Thank You. You are right the stream was not clear hence i was getting the segmentation fault putting cin.clear(); solved the problem

Answer (score 1):

In the loop

```
for(int i=0;i<y;i++) {
    cout<<a[i]<<" "<<b[i]<<"\n";
}
```

if one of the indexes is `out_of _range` there will be an `out_of_range exception` thrown, witch is bound to happen since you use the size of `vector` `b` to print `vector` `a`, because you are not catching this exception, the program will crash.

Use foreach loops to avoid this:

Use foreach loop to avoid this, for instance:

```
vector<int> a;
for(int i : a){
  cout << a;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also try this if it suits:

```
void print(vector<string> a,vector<int> b)
{int y=0;
y= b.size();

int x = a.size();

// min(x,y) is the minimum of x and y values
for(int i=0;i< min(x,y);i++)
    {cout<<a[i]<<" "<<b[i]<<"\n";
     }

}
```